# What is the `AssetBundle` dropdown in the inspector for?

Tags: unity

I know what an AssetBundle is alright. But what is the dropdown at the bottom right for?

[image]

Apparently you can choose an asset bundle for this asset to belong to. So what? What happens when you choose one? Does Unity build an AssetBundle for you? Where?

Comment: Worth noting that AssetBundles are a Pro feature only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity 5.1 Asset bundle for windows](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/105039/unity-5-1-asset-bundle-for-windows)